# How to find the spot, which is adding event listners?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I have a Wordpress/Elementor website and there are some links with anchors on them. Something is always adding 3 same click listeners to the links, so the scrolling event happens 3 times and it looks just broken. Is is possible to track the file which is adding the listeners?

Comment: You can try to find them on chrome DevTools, under (Sources -> Global Listeners).

Comment: thx, i have removed all global events, but its still there